# Where to take briefcases from?

Tags: black-friday

In [Black Friday](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/39242/black-friday), when all three sales tables on the right have been used up, [the rulebook](http://riograndegames.com/uploads/Game/Game_374_gameRules.pdf) says to reload table 2 and use that one for the rest of the game.

> After all markers are adjusted, he places the drawn briefcases in the market. The player places all colored briefcases from the table that initiated the price adjustment into the bag. If a sales table initiated the adjustment, the players place the black briefcases from this table in the bag, too. **Then, the players use the next sales table.** After the third sales table is cleared, the players load the second sales table. When that is cleared, **they load the second again and will continue to reload the second table** for the remainder of the game.

**Where are the briefcases taken from to reload this table - The market or the bag?**

Comment: An early prototype translation says, "If the cubes came from the Sold Stocks area, the next Sold Stocks area down will be used next. (If all three have been used, form a new Sold Stocks area by taking cubes from the Market, plus a Collapse cube.)" **Don't take this as canon**, this was an early prototype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a bad translation from German to English.

Here's the corresponding paragraph from the [german rulebook](http://www.brettspiele-report.de/images/s/schwarzer_freitag/Spielanleitung_Schwarzer_Freitag.pdf) (no prototype!), page 5:

> Nachdem alle Kurse angepasst wurden, kommen die gezogenen Aktenkoffer in den Markt. Die Leiste, die die Preisänderung ausgelöst hat, wird komplett (ggf. inklusive schwarzer Koffer) in den Beutel
>   geworfen. Hat eine Verkaufsleiste die Preisänderung ausgelöst, wird ab sofort die nächste Verkaufsleiste darunter genutzt. Erst wenn die dritte Verkaufsleiste abgeräumt wurde, wird wieder eine **Verkaufsleiste aus dem Markt bestückt**. Hierbei wird die zweite Verkaufsleiste genutzt.

Let me translate the last two sentences:
"Only after the third sales table has been cleared, a sales table is filled again **from the market**. This is done using the second sales table."

The german rulebook is the original because the game designer (Friedemann Friese) is german.

Comment: Almost a year later, but I'm glad to finally have an answer to this question. Thank you for going to the effort of looking this up.